# Is there a built-in way to hash, or digest, or string-serialize arbitrary cell array entries?

Tags: matlab

Short version:

I'm looking for a *built-in* hashing function `u` such that the expressions `isequal(u(A), u(B))` and `isequal(A, B)` always produce the same result, for any values `A` and `B`.

(Or, less formally: two values `A` and `B` should be equal *if and only if* their `u`-transforms are equal.)

---

Long version:

Some code of mine applies `unique(..., 'stable')` to an input `table X` as follows:

```
[~, IX, IZ] = unique(X, 'stable');
```

Unfortunately, this code fails if any column `X.(j)` of `X` violates the constraint

```
~iscell(X.(j)) || iscellstr(X.(j))
```

Granted, this is behavior is as described in the documentation for `unique`, but it narrows the scope of my code unnecessarily.  After all, all I need are the index vectors `IX` and `IZ`.

I'd like to get around this restriction by pre-processing `X` to generate an intermediate table `Y` in which every column `X.(j)` of `X` that violates the constraint above is replaced by one in which every entry has been replaced by a suitable value compatible with `unique`'s limitations.  More specifically, I'm looking for some transform `u` such that, for any column `X.(j)` of `X`,

1. `isequal(u(X(i1, j)), u(X(i2, j)))` is equivalent to `isequal(X(i1, j), X(i2, j))`, for any pair of row indices `i1` and `i2`; and
2. `u(X.(j))` is a suitable argument for `unique`.

(The first condition above can be stated as: two column entries are equal *if and only if* their `u`-transforms are equal.)

(FWIW, as far as my application goes, the columns of `X` may be safely assumed not to contain `NaN` or `<undefined>` values.)

There are many possible ways one can envision implementing such a transform `u`, but I'm not sure how best to go about it in `MATLAB`.

Through Google, I've found a few 3rd-party functions that may be fit the bill, but if there's any built-in alternative, I'd prefer to go with that.

Comment: Relevant: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/serializing-deserializing-matlab-data

Answer (score 1):

As noted in this [blog post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/serializing-deserializing-matlab-data), you can use the undocumented built-in `getByteStreamFromArray`:

```
x = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 1e7};
% unique(x); % error

if ~(~iscell(x) || iscellstr(x))
    y = cellfun(@(c)(char(getByteStreamFromArray(c))), x, 'uniformoutput', false);
end

[vals, inds] = unique(y, 'stable');
xUnique = cellfun(@(c)(getArrayFromByteStream(uint8(c))), vals, 'uniformoutput', false)
```